# How does the order between DISTINCT, ORDER BY, and TOP matter?

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement) says:

> The actual physical
> execution of the statement is determined by the query processor and the order may vary from this list.
>
> 1. FROM
> 2. ON
> 3. JOIN
> 4. WHERE
> 5. GROUP BY
> 6. WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
> 7. HAVING
> 8. SELECT
> 9. DISTINCT
> 10. ORDER BY
> 11. TOP

I was wondering how the order between  DISTINCT,  ORDER BY, and   TOP  matters?
(I can guess the order between ORDER BY and TOP matters, because TOP only keeps the top n records.)

Could you give examples where the order between them matters?

Comment: One would have to determine distinct output before ordering, so distinct is first. Same goes for distinct and top. I can't imagine a scenario where the execution path would differ when any combination of those three are included in SQL.

Comment: @JNevill, DISTINCT _after_ ORDER BY will give the same result as _before_ ORDER BY.

Comment: That ordering is suitable for pedagogical purposes only. In real life the engine will cheat, apply shortcuts, turn the query inside out, etc. to run the query in an efficient way.

Comment: @TheImpaler, more important, the ordering _defines_ the result.

Answer (score 2):

As a very quick example:

```sql
SELECT TOP (2)
       DISTINCT
       c
FROM (VALUES('c'),('a'),('a'),('b'))V(C)
ORDER BY V.C;
```

If the `DISTINCT` was applied *after* the `TOP` and `ORDER BY` you would end up with 1 `'a'` row; the rows are ordered (`'a'`,`'a'`,`'b'`,`'c'`), the `TOP(2)` taken (`'a'`,`'a'`), and then the `DISTINCT` rows returned (`'a'`).

If `DISTINCT` and `TOP` were performed first, you *might* end up with `'a'` and `'c'` because the `TOP` rows would be arbitrary.

Comment: And DISTINCT first will give you `('c', 'a', 'b')`, which ORDER BY then sorts as `('a', 'b', 'c')`. If you do ORDER BY first, you'll get `('a', 'a', 'b', 'c')`, which DISTINCT turns into `('a', 'b', 'c')`. I.e. same result!

Comment: In *truth* the `DISTINCT` is likely to sort the data the same as the `ORDER BY` here, @jarlh , but this is intentionally an overly simplified example to demonstrate what *might* happen.

Comment: Consider my comment as an addendum to your answer (to the question '_How does the order between DISTINCT, ORDER BY, and TOP matter?_'.)